# Wordpress jquery ui error

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

i've installed wordpress on my server but when i try to add new page switching to text editor i retrieve in console that error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'a.curCSS(l,"padding"+this,true)') jquery-ui.min.js:14
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'switchEditors.switchto') post.php:257
```

I downloaded latest version of wordpress so i think that jquery is the latest.

How can i solve? Which could be the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with wordpress but if it includes the latest jQuery version that should be the problem cause the `$.curCSS` function was removed from jQuery since 1.8 as explained in the [release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/) :

> **What’s Been Removed**
>
> [...]
>
> $.curCSS: This method was simply an alias for jQuery.css() from jQuery 1.3 onward. Although it has never been part of the documented API, some external code has been known to use it, perhaps thinking it was “more efficient.” Now it’s “more gone.”